# Python name errors

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to learn python tkinter but a lot of the names (according to the documentation) in tkinter are giving me errors. I tried in eclipse with pydev and even though the editor tells me "tkinter.font" is fine it gives me an error when i run this:

import tkinter

print(tkinter.font)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'font'

If i try this in IDLE it works but i tried some other names in IDLE such as scrolledtext, turtle, dnd and they give me attribute errors.

Can someone please help? this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`tkinter.font`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-modules) is a *module* in the Tkinter package.  This means that, normally, it is not imported when you do `import tkinter`.

To access `tkinter.font`, you have to explicitly import it:

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> tkinter.font
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'font'
>>>
>>> import tkinter.font
>>> tkinter.font
<module 'tkinter.font' from 'C:\\Python33\\lib\\tkinter\\font.py'>
>>>
```

---

For some reason however, `tkinter.font` *is* imported when you do `import tkinter` in IDLE.  I don't know the reason for this, but I would guess that it is for convenience.  Regardless, it would probably be best to always import `tkinter.font` (and similar modules) explicitly so that your code will work both inside and outside of IDLE.

Comment: ohhh, for some reason i forgot that modules are not imported. i done dir(tkinter) in IDLE and seen font so i thought i could use it. I probably would have realised my mistake if IDLE hadn't confused me even more. I thought there was something wrong with my installation. Thanks.